# SSAS Tabular - Process model but only specific partition

Tags: ssas, tabular, xmla

We process our tabular model each night using a SQL Server Analysis Services Command in a SQL job step.  The type if ProcessFull.  As our data has grown, our processing time has also increased.  So, we're looking at partitioning our large tables to decrease our processing time.

Current command:

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>Model</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
</Process>
```

To process a specific table partition:

```
<Process xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>Model</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>Model</CubeID>
    <MeasureGroupID>factNursingQueries_[guid]</MeasureGroupID>
    <PartitionID>factNursingQueries_[guid]</PartitionID>
  </Object>
</Process>
```

I realize ProcessFull on the whole model every time may not be a good long-term approach, but we're new to tabular and still learning.

Is there a way to process the whole model but specify a single partition for specific tables?

Update:
Found the Analysis Services Processing Task in SSIS toolbox.  Maybe we need to move from script in SQL Job to SSIS package...
[image: SSIS_task_example]

Comment: Do people use Analysis Services Processing Tasks in SSIS to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is. you can use Analysis Services Processing Task, then in Process Setting you add the tables, if the table has partition you would be able to see the partitions (as your screen shot) and only select the partition you have.